# Many to Many in GAE/J using JPA 1

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

How to implement a many to many relationship in GAE using Java Persistence API 1? I want to implement something like in this link but it's in python: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling

I can't find examples about it.

Answer (score 1):

Since all docs for GAE JPA say that Many-Many is not supported, then you can rule that out ... with that version of their plugin.

Obviously using v2.x of the GAE JPA plugin means you can have M-N unowned relations, just as you can in any other JPA implementation.